# Active Admin showing count of related data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a common devise rails 4 setup and Im now playing with active admin.

Lets say I have a model

```
class User
  has_many :customers
end

class Customer
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The database with index and everything is fine.

I have a simple user.rb in my activeadmin folder:

```
  index do
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end
```

Im trying to show the count of customers per User. How can i realise that? The AA documentation is kinda thin at that.
I tried `column :customer.count` But thats just rubbish.

Any ideas or suggestions?
best regards
denym_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `column("Customers Count"){|u| u.customers.count }` to your index. Bot he would do a count query for every user. Shouldnt be a problem unless you have like 100,000 users.

Smarter way to solve this, is to use counter-cache possibility.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter_cache

then you just have to add `column :customers_count` to your index